# Use '\n' as a field separator in awk command

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have multiple lines, and i need to select one of them, i have found the required lines using grep,
but now i want only the first line from the result.
How can i do it using, `grep`, `awk`, `sed` etc..

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
This is seventh line.
```

Using grep i got the o/p
grep "This is s" `file.txt`.

```
This is second line.
This is seventh line.
```

now i need the first line from this.
How can i use `'\n'` as a field separator.

Comment: You never need grep and awk. Whatever you're doing can be done entirely in awk. Note that your posted question and the answer you accepted have absolutely nothing to do with fields being separated by `\n` so your subject line is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the first line that matches `This is s` and quit with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/This is s/{print $0; exit}'
This is second line.
```

However `GNU grep` has the `-m` option which stops are the given number of matches:

```
$ grep -Fm 1 'This is s' file
This is second line.
```

Note: the `-F` is for fixed string matching instead of regular expressions.

And for completeness with `sed` you could do:

```
$ sed '/This is s/!d;q' file
This is second line.
```

However the example seems slightly strange as you could just do `grep 'second' file`.

Comment: Ya i got that i can do this,
But actually my query is, is there a way to, tokenize the lines using, awk, sed or grep.
now here we know that there is a string like "This is s", but what if i dont know, and i need the first line.

Comment: All 3 examples find the first match only against a given pattern. `awk` splits records by newlines by default. As far as I can tell I have answer the question, if this is not the case please edit the question to make it clear what you want with an example input and expect output.

Comment: Thanks sudo, :) that was just an example, i created to explain my problem. And i think i was not able to explain the problem properly.

Can you please tell, now how can i get the second line, form there. If i dont know the contents of those lines.
Because i tried it but could not quite get it.

Comment: Ok got that, :)
"`awk` splits records by newlines by default"

Thanks. :)